# Vuex with custom class javascript cant commit mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my first project with vue and vuex.
The project is a little sales force application.

Problem comes when I introduced my javascript class to place in store

I recieve undefined when I try to delete or update the store

My actions is so:

```
export const addProduct = ({ state, commit }, product, variant) => {
  const exists = state.cart.find(i => {
    i.RoaCodart === product.ranCodart;
  });

  if (exists) {
    commit("updateQuantity", product, variant);
  } else {
    commit("addProduct", product, variant);
  }
};

export const removeProduct = ({state, commit}, product)=>{
    console.log('removeProduct ' + product)
    const index = state.cart.findIndex(i => i.RoaCodart === product.RoaCodart);
    commit("removeProduct", index);
};
```

and this is my mutations:

```
import RigheOrdine from "../store/modules/RigheOrdine.js";

export const addProduct = (state, product, variant) => {
  console.log(variant)
  const row = new RigheOrdine("001", product.ranCodart, variant, product.ranDescri, product.ranPrezz1, "00001", new Date().getDate(), "001", "", "00001");
  row.RoaQuanti = 1; 
  state.cart.push(row);

};

export const updateQuantity = (state, product, variant) => {
  const index = state.cart.indexOf(product);
  let orderItem = state.cart[index];
  if (orderItem !== undefined) orderItem.RoaQuanti++;

  state.cart.splice(index, 1, orderItem); //Object.assign({}, orderItem) ??
};

export const removeProduct = (state, index)=>{
  state.cart.splice(index, 1);
};
```

So whenever I try to detect the product in store I recive undefined!

```
import Variants from "./Variants.vue";
export default {
  name: "product-details",
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  components: {
    Variants
  },
  methods: {
    back() {
      this.$router.go(-1);
    },
    add(varianti) {
      if(!varianti.length)
       // this.$store.dispatch("addProduct", this.product, '');
        this.$store.dispatch('addProduct', { product, variant });
      else
        varianti.forEach(variant => {
           this.$store.dispatch("addProduct", this.product, variant);
      });
    },
    qty(codart){
       return this.$store.getters.quantity(codart);
     }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: From where you are dispatching `addProduct`? Can you share the codes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send Object as the second parameter if you need more than one Payload. [See here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)

> In most cases, the payload should be an object so that it can contain multiple fields

```js
// methods
add(varianti) {
  // make sure this.product & varianti exists
  console.log('this.product: ', this.product);
  console.log('varianti: ', varianti);

  if(!varianti.length) {
    this.$store.dispatch('addProduct', { this.product, varianti });
  } else {
    varianti.forEach(variant => {
       this.$store.dispatch("addProduct", this.product, variant);
    });
  }
},

// action
export const addProduct = ({ state, commit }, payload) => {
  // local variable
  const product = payload.product;
  const variant = payload.variant;

  const exists = state.cart.find(i => {
i.RoaCodart === product.ranCodart;
  });

  if (exists) {
    commit("updateQuantity", { product, variant });
  } else {
    commit("addProduct", { product, variant });
  }
};


// mutation
export const addProduct = (state, { product, variant }) => {
  console.log(variant)
  const row = new RigheOrdine("001", product.ranCodart, variant, product.ranDescri, product.ranPrezz1, "00001", new Date().getDate(), "001", "", "00001");
  row.RoaQuanti = 1; 
  state.cart.push(row);

};

export const updateQuantity = (state, { product, variant }) => {
  const index = state.cart.indexOf(product);
  let orderItem = state.cart[index];
  if (orderItem !== undefined) orderItem.RoaQuanti++;

  state.cart.splice(index, 1, orderItem); //Object.assign({}, orderItem) ??
};
```

Comment: i try but get Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ranCodart' of undefined"

Comment: Can you share the code, it would be helpful to find out the issue?

Comment: Did you change your action call in your handler? This comment also applies to mutations: `export const addProduct = (state, product, variant) ` should be `export const addProduct = (state,{product, variant})`. I am using [ES6 object destructuring](https://alligator.io/js/object-array-destructuring-es2015/)

Comment: yes and now get Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot destructure property `product` of 'undefined' or 'null'."

Comment: Updated action/mutaion.. also you need to send Object from where dispatching `addProduct`

Comment: You need to dispatch like: `this.$store.dispatch('addProduct', { product, variant });`

Comment: Can you share the `...dispatch('addProduct', ...)` code?

Comment: i posted the code above. If i simplify without variant and simple addProduct action i see the code work. The state.cart is pushed. But if i try also to simple delete i cant!

Comment: tks for help and patient. im a newbie with vue and js... from about three months

Comment: i see that payload (on vue tool of chrome) is different from RigheOrdini that i push in store. Payload is different on click of details page and also in productlist page. I should be the answer??

Comment: Make sure you have correct datas while `dispatching`. You can just simply do Console log in everywhere & see what data/payload value is.

Comment: ok but they not should be the same right? the object i show in details page are different from productlistpage and both differs from my RigheOrdini class